# SQL Stored Process: If statement not behaving as expected

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, stored-procedures

Attempting to create a stored process for MySQL.  It contains a basic if-statement. The current script is below:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_pay_raise;

DELIMITER @@
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_pay_raise
     (IN inEmpId INT,
      IN inPercentageRaise DOUBLE(4,2),
      OUT outErrorCode INT)
BEGIN
    IF (@inPercentageRaise <= 0.0) THEN
        SELECT -3 INTO errorCode
    ELSE
        SELECT -2 INTO errorCode
    END IF;
END @@
DELIMITER ;
```

The above doesn't work as expected.  If I provide a `inPercentageRaise` which is less than zero, for ex.

```
CALL sp_pay_raise(0,-1.0, @out)
SELECT @out;
```

The database shows @out = -2.  Is the if-statement which is written incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@` is used for [Session variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html). While inside a stored procedure, you don't need to use `@` for the input params. Otherwise, MySQL will look for a similar name pre-defined Session variable. Since it does not find it; it assumes its values as `Null`

There are other errors also. You have a typo; instead of using `outErrorCode` param, you are using a different undefined variable `errorCode`

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_pay_raise;

DELIMITER @@
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_pay_raise
     (IN inEmpId INT,
      IN inPercentageRaise DOUBLE(4,2),
      OUT outErrorCode INT)
BEGIN
    IF (inPercentageRaise <= 0.0) THEN  -- Remove @ from here.
        SELECT -3 INTO outErrorCode  -- It should be outErrorCode instead of errorCode
    ELSE
        SELECT -2 INTO outErrorCode  -- It should be outErrorCode instead of errorCode
    END IF;
END @@
DELIMITER ;
```